# Detect Page Name In CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I hope this isn't a completely stupid question, but I just couldn't find the answer to this anywhere!

Is there some function that comes with CakePHP that allows you to detect what page the user is on? (eg - Detect what action they are on).

I want to do this so I can display an active class on my navigation bar if they are on the correct page.

Please let me know if there's a better way to this than detecting the page/action they are on!!

Thanks,

Adam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Check out the `$this->params` array inside your view to see what you have available :)

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, `$this->params['action']` You got it! Cheers mate.